# C# pass parameter to method with type known only in runtime

Tags: c#, generics

Intellisense gives me an error `'myType' is variable but used like a type`

```
var myType = myObject.GetType();
var result = MyMethod<myType>(param);
```

Where:

```
var myObject = new MyType(); // MyType extends MyBaseType

public static string MyMethod<TArgs>(string param)
   where TArgs : MyBaseType
{
    // Do stuff...
}
```

So at the runtime the `myObject.GetType()` is known (it's `MyType` in our case).

**Question:**

How could I in a right way pass `myType` "dynamically" (which in a runtime could be `MyType`) to `public static string MyMethod<TArgs>(string param)` method?

Comment: typeof(myObject) rather than .GetType() ??

Comment: What's the point of the type arguments here? For runtime purposes you better should use `object` or `Type` as a function parameter instead of a type parameter

Comment: Basically you can´t. You already mentioned that `myType` is a *runtime*-type which isn´t known during *compile*-time. So whilst you can *call* the method with the runtime-type inferred to the generic method (as shown in the duplicate) you can *not* expect the instance returned from `MyMethod` to be striongly typed. This is all you know is that it deried from `object`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Thats not correct. You can do it by using reflection: typeof(this)
        .GetMethod("MyMethod")
        .MakeGenericMethod(myType)
        .Invoke(this, new object[] { param });

Comment: @RomanoZumbé The point of my comment was that the instance that is returned by `Invoke` is just an `object`. The actual runtime-type however cannot be inferred from the compiler.